# Workflow Questions (I'm a Beginner)

Tags: workflow

Please bare with me as I try to explain this. Please use the below picture as reference:

[image: Reference Picture]

Currently the list is imported through a flow that grabs the data from "Forms". What I want to do now is create  2 workflows:

1. When the Status is selected to Complete I would like it to send an e-mail to the person under title and include the Comments in the e-mail body.
2. When the Status is selected to In Progress I would like it to send and email to one specific person with the comments part of the email body.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Antonio,

First off, welcome to the community.  I have found this community an invaluable resource over many years and only recently decided to start contributing back.  Hopefully you will feel the same.

Second, you should edit your post to conform to do the following:

1. Have a more descriptive title for future users to search for,
2. Obfuscate your company's logo (in your example image) and,
3. Obfuscate your co-workers' email addresses (in your example image) so that they don't get spammed/phished.  (see the first image of this post).

Third,  You will need to have SharePoint Designer 2013 installed on your computer to perform the tasks to achieve what you are trying to do.  it can be downloaded [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35491).

The Workflow and configuration below is a 2010 SharePoint Workflow that will run on 2013 (there are only a few differences between 2010 workflows and 2013) 2010 workflows are backwards compatible with 2013.  I included images of the contents of the emails to expand - for clarity.

When choosing the email recipient (you did not specify who was to receive the email when the status column was "In Progress") so i used the same email setting as for the Status == "Completed" email.  When you click on the address book icon to the right of the email address field to configure the recipient, you can do a number of things:

- Choose a Workflow variable or Form Field  (Green in image below)
- Choose a specific person from Active Directory (assuming that AD is synced with your SharePoint environment. (Orange Box below)
- Choose a SharePoint Group, (Yellow in image below) and
- Choose the user who created the current Item. (Blue in image below)
- Manually enter an email address

In order to get the title field into the "TO:" field of the email, you need to choose Workflow lookup and ensure that the fields in the popup menu are 'Current Item' and 'Title'.

Also, to get the 'Comments' field into the email body 
Click on the 'Add or Change Lookup' and ensure the following two fields are selected in the popup:  'Current Item' and 'Comments'  it will resemble the second and third pictures in this post.

> **If This Post Answers Your Question, Please Mark As Answered**

[image: Email Recipient Choice Box]

[image: 'Completed' Status Email Config]

[image: 'In Progress' Status Email Config]

This is what your basic workflow should look like.

[image: Very Basic SharePoint Workflow]

*Click the 'Save' button on the Ribbon.  Then click the 'Publish' button* **<-- THIS IS CRITICAL**  otherwise this workflow will not run.

**The Second Most Critical thing you must configure is this:**

Go to the List Configuration Screen in SP Designer and click on the workflow you just configured, see here:

[image: Go to the List Configuration Screen in SP Designer and click on the workflow you just configured]

Then ***Ensure*** that the "Start Workflow Automatically When Item Is Changed" checkbox is checked - As in the image Below.  After checking the checkbox, either hold CTRL and press S or click 'Save' in the Ribbon to commit these changes.

[image: Ensure that the "Start Workflow Automatically When Item Is Changed" checkbox is checked]

Comment: Thank You Very Much! And thanks for pointing out the obvious that I should hide sensitive material. This worked perfectly. Thanks,